# ios - I have a 2-button UIAlertView, how do I know which button is pressed?

Tags: ios, ios5, uialertview

I have this 2-button alert view:

```
UIAlertView* message = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle: @"Delete?" message: @"This business will be deleted permenently." delegate: nil
                           cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: @"Delete", nil];

[message show];
```

I also have this method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Delete"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Button DELETE was selected.");
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Cancel"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Button CANCEL was selected.");
    }
}
```

and I added this to the .h file:

```
<UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Right now when either button is pressed, it just closes the dialog. That is ok for cancel, but how do I know when the delete button is pressed?

Thanks!

Comment: [UIAlertViewDelegate protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) - **do make the effort** to read the documentation.

Comment: @H2CO3 I updated my question with more code than I posted originally. Just not sure how to have the user's choice recognized

Comment: Doesn't NikosM's answer solve your problem?

Comment: @H2CO3 I am trying one other thing now, and was going to try his solution as the very next one :)

Comment: Just one question though. I got it to recognize which of the buttons was pressed, but that happens in the delegate. How do I send that information to the original method where the dialog was shown?

Comment: you can't really do it and you should not need it anyways if you have designed your code well.

Comment: @H2CO3 is the general pattern that I should call a method to perform the chosen action from the delegate?

Comment: no, you should rather perform the needed actions in the delegate method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to implement the `– alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method of the UIAlertViewDelegate. You also have to set the delegate when initialising the alert view.

E.g.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

   if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        //Do something
   } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
       //Do something else
   }
}
```

The cancel button's index is 0.

Comment: take a look at my updated question. I added more code. I am alsmost there, just not sure how to connect the actual alert to have the choice recognized

Comment: You shouldn't rely on specific index values. Use the `alertView.cancelButtonIndex` and `alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex` properties.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `nil` to the `delegate` parameter when you create the alert view. You need to pass `self` instead. As you have it now, the `clickedButtonAtIndex:` method is never called.

```
UIAlertView* message = [[UIAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle: @"Delete?" 
    message: @"This business will be deleted permenently." 
    delegate: self
    cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel" 
    otherButtonTitles: @"Delete", nil];


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
        // Cancel was tapped
    } else if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex) {
        // The other button was tapped
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
message.delegate = self;
...

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
     NSLog(@"Button %d was clicked", buttonIndex);
}
```

and the class must be declared to meet the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol.

Comment: "and the class must be declared to meet the protocol." - it is not actually a requirement, only a formal thing for helping the compiler.